# Blackberry Mobile Application Development

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, platform, mobile-application

I developed an application for iPhone. Based on suggestions from different blogs I am writing an application from scratch for Blackberry.

Can anyone suggest basic things needed to setup for starting mobile application for Blackberry,

- like platform required(is it Java or can we use any other)
- preferable IDE to be used
- I need to develop on i-Mac
- which RIM OS is to be targeted

Comment: you should go through this link and explore you can find how to start Developing your application http://us.blackberry.com/developers/started/

Comment: Please suggest for development on MAC Machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start your application by exploring the [API documentation](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/index.html),and the [Getting Started](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/started/) section of the BlackBerry developer zone.